# Oracle invalid character external table

Tags: oracle11g, invalid-characters, external-tables

I'am new with oracle..
and i need someone for helping me with my problem..

I was trying to make an External Table in Oracle (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit), and i got an error like this

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE LOAD_OrderDetails
  2  (
  3  OrderID Number(5),
  4  ProductID Number(25),
  5  UnitPrice Decimal(5),
  6  Quantity Number(5),
  7  Discount Decimal(5)
  8  )
  9  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
 10  (
 11  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
 12  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_dir
 13  LOCATION (`OrderDetails.txt')
 14  )
 15  REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
LOCATION (`OrderDetails.txt')
          *
ERROR at line 13:
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I already check my file and its already put on the right directory and with the same name as on my coding 'OrderDetails'.
I tried with another name an its going the same..
I don't know where's the problem and I need someone for helping me..

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> LOCATION (`OrderDetails.txt')

You have a **back tick** instead of **single-quotation** mark in the beginning. Change it to -

```
LOCATION ('OrderDetails.txt')
```